# How to reduce real memory consumption ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

My iphone application have a lot of high resolution images (eg: 2898 × 779 pixels dimension)  and the whole project folder is only 17mb in size but if i run the application and when the first view is loaded the real memory and dirty memory showing in the VM Tracker in Instruments is more than 62mb.Can anyone help me to avoid this?Any suggestions will be thankful.

Comment: Can you please share some code how you are loading images or view?

Comment: For images you reference repeatedly, don't just load images and keep the references around.  Make use of `+imageNamed` essentially every time you need an image, and release the images as soon as you no longer have immediate need for them.  The system will then cache the "old" images and will give you back the same image object on the next `imageNamed` request for it (so it's real fast), but will delete images that are not recently used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Images once loaded into memory lose (most of?) their compression. So unfortunately, the images may not look big when on disk (bundled in the app) but they can be a lot bigger once loaded into your app.

one 2898x779 image in ram will effectively use 2898x779x4 bytes = ~9mb, compare that with how big your image is on disk and you should see the difference.

so to actually answer your question, either downsize your images (because your devices screen is probably not that big, unless retina ipad or something) or use a `CATiledLayer` which will only load up parts of the image that are visible on the screen, and not the whole image.

Comment: I think this is true only if images are in JPEG format. If images are in PNG format than it is already uncompressed format.

Comment: PNG's do have compression, it is just a lossless compression compared to jpg's lossy compression (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics)

Comment: The question is about memory use, that means after the file has been decompressed into memory. It does not matter if PNG or JPEG compression was used on disk, the thing that matters is how big the decompressed image is and that depends on the width and height of the image, not the PNG or JPEG compression method on disk.

Answer (score 2):

***5 tips to reduce memory issues in iOS apps***

**1. Use virtual memory**
iOS doesn’t use swap file but it does support virtual memory. If an app keeps a lot of data in memory for random access you want to organize it as a mapfile rather then loading it to RAM with
malloc()
. An easiest way to do that is to call
NSData initWithContentsOfMappedFile:

**2. Avoid stacking autoreleased objects**
When you instantiate objects like NSString with no explicit allocation they live until the release of your autorelease pool – typically until your app quits. Extensive usage of such techniques may lead to a lot of garbage in RAM. Use
NSString initWithContentsOfFile:
so you can later release it instead of
NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:
. The same rule applies to
UIImage imageNamed:
– this is not recommended to use for image loading.

**3. Handle memory warnings**
Unload unnecessary resources when handling memory warning. Even if you can’t unload any of your stuff call
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning]
in all your UIViewControllers. That will by default free some resources like UI controls on non-front views. Failing to handle this event may make iOS decide that your app deserves killing.

**4. Consider limited usage of animated view transitions**
Animations like flip transition are noticed to cause RAM usage spikes when executed. This feature is very neat and should be used in many cases but it may trigger memory warnings in a heavily loaded multitasking environment. In particular we strongly recommend to avoid animating OpenGL views.

**5. Test your memory footprint on device**
Use instruments to test. The most useful tools are Allocations, Leaks and Activity Monitor. Testing on simulator is not relevant in most cases since its memory footprint tends to be completely different. Once you test you can figure out how much RAM each part of your app uses, where are the bottlenecks and how you can optimize.

***From http://surgeworks.com/***

Comment: Perhaps you should give credit: http://surgeworks.com/blog/lab-mobile/iphone/5-tips-to-reduce-memory-issues-in-ios-apps